# Why does the game's connection to the proxy server connection time-out?

Tags: python, tcp, proxy, minecraft

I'm writing a TCP proxy server for Minecraft In python.
But when I run the program and try to connect to the proxy it just says that it is connecting and then
eventually times out

I am running the Minecraft server I am testing with as well as the proxy on my computer
the server on port 25565
the proxy on port 8080

although I have tested it on mineplex and hypixel as well
and it did not work on them either

How can I fix the issue

The code:

````
import socket
from threading import Thread

class Proxy2Server(Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.game = None
        self.port = port
        self.host = host

        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.connect((host, port))

    def run(self):
        while True:

            data = self.server.recv(4096)
            print("[server]", data)

            if data:
                self.game.sendall(data)

class Game2Proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, host, port):

        self.server = None
        self.port = port
        self.host = host

        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        sock.bind((host, port))
        sock.listen(1)

        self.game, addr = sock.accept()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            data = self.game.recv(4096)
            print("[client]", data)

            if data:
                self.server.sendall(data)

class Proxy(Thread):
    def __init__(self, from_host, to_host, from_port, to_port):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()

        self.from_host = from_host
        self.to_host = to_host
        self.from_port = from_port
        self.to_port = to_port

    def run(self):
        while True:
            print(f"[proxy {self.from_host}:{self.from_port}] setting up")

            self.g2p = Game2Proxy(self.from_host, self.from_port)
            self.p2s = Proxy2Server(self.to_host, self.to_port)

            print(f"[proxy {self.from_host}:{self.from_port}] connection established")

            self.g2p.server = self.p2s.server
            self.p2s.game = self.g2p.game


from_host = input("from-host$ ")
from_port = int(input("from-port$ "))
to_host = input("to-host$ ")
to_port = int(input("port$ "))

ProxyServer = Proxy(from_host, to_host, from_port, to_port)

ProxyServer.start()```
````

Comment: Your proxy code is very far from correct. If you don't want your proxy to do anything fancy with the data, why not just use one of the many simple TCP redirectors that already exist, like `socat`?

Comment: I wanted to write my own because I don't have much to do in lockdown